# Using --config flag with the Python GDAL gdal.Translate()

Tags: python, gdal

So I've recently learned that GDAL and OGR command line utilities can be used as functions now.  See [this site](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2015/10/gdal-and-ogr-utilities-as-library.html) for more info.  For example:

```
from osgeo import gdal
tmp_ds = gdal.Warp('temp', 'in.tif', format = 'MEM', dstSRS = 'EPSG:3857')
gdal.Translate('out.png', tmp_ds, format = 'PNG')
```

This works amazing!  But one thing I can't figure out is how to pass in the --config flag.  In my case, I am using gdal_translate to convert a US Topo GeoPDF to GeoTiff, exporting out certain PDF layers:

```
gdal_translate -of “GTiff” --config GDAL_PDF_LAYER “Map_Collar,Map_Frame.Terrain” ustopo.pdf ustopo_terrain.tif
```

I've tried adding to the gdal.Translate in 2 ways:

```
gdal.Translate('out.tif', tmp_ds, format = 'GTiff',options='--config GDAL_PDF_LAYER “Map_Collar,Map_Frame.Terrain”')
```

and

```
gdal.Translate('out.tif', tmp_ds, format = 'GTiff',config='GDAL_PDF_LAYER “Map_Collar,Map_Frame.Terrain”')
```

Neither work.  I am totally stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would post it in comment, but can't yet. 
Anyway, when I am working with GDAL i usually use this:

```
gdal.SetConfigOption('COMPRESS_OVERVIEW', 'LZW')
```

which basically is

```
gdal.SetConfigOption(option, settings)
```

or when you are creating a file driver you can set options like this:

```
        format = "GTiff"
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
        dst_ds = driver.Create(out_file, xsize, ysize, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW', 'TFW=YES'])
```

another thing could be this (i am not really sure about the correct syntax for GDAL PDF LAYER:

```
co = ['GDAL_PDF_LAYER']
gdal.Translate('out.tif', tmp_ds, format = 'GTiff',options=co)
```